# Legend load event in ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-js-api, arcgis-online

I am working on arcgis map JavaScript API and i want to show map layer legend with close icon but i am unable to find legend load event to show the same. Legend along with close icon is shown in below image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3aou.png)

Comment: are you using a custom widget? .. what is the relation between the close button and the "load" event? .. why you need the "load" event?

Comment: i am not using custom widget , using default legend widget only , but problem is my client need close button along with legend widget so that he can close it without switching  off the layer. basically when legend will load then i am going to show the close button on top to legend window

Answer (score 0):

You can access the dom node of the legend widget after it was added to the `mapview.ui` with the `container` property of the legend widget.

This script below was taken from a [sample demo](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-legend/index.html)

```
require([
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/widgets/Legend",
    "esri/WebMap"
  ], function(MapView, Legend, WebMap) {
    var webmap = new WebMap({
      portalItem: {
        // autocasts as new PortalItem()
        id: "4abe6a830b8f466dacf8abfde567a781"
      }
    });

    var view = new MapView({
      container: "viewDiv",
      map: webmap
    });

    view.when(function() {
      // get the first layer in the collection of operational layers in the WebMap
      // when the resources in the MapView have loaded.
      var featureLayer = webmap.layers.getItemAt(0);

      var legend = new Legend({
        view: view,
        layerInfos: [
          {
            layer: featureLayer,
            title: "NY Educational Attainment"
          }
        ]
      });

      // Add widget to the bottom right corner of the view
      view.ui.add(legend, "bottom-right");

      //Now you can access the legend domNode and add a close button
      console.log(legend.container)
    });
  });
```